# Computational Complexity of Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, operations-research

I've been asked to code two instances of Dijkstra's Algorithm. The first instance should determine the shortest path length between node 0 and each other node in the graph (in order of increasing path length) and then return the path length of a specified end node. The second instance uses the same code, but terminates as soon as the specified end node is reached.

I know that the first instance has a theoretical complexity of $O(nm)$ (where $n=|V|$ and $m=|E|$), but I can't work out the complexity of the second instance.

I have a feeling it might be either $O(n)$ or $O(n^2)$, can someone either confirm or correct this?

Comment: If I am right, in the worst-case of the second instance, i.e. when the path to the target node is the longest of all, you in fact solve the first instance ("terminates as soon" does not occur). Hence the worst case complexities are the same.

Comment: Thank you, I don’t know why I didn’t think of it like that!

Comment: Probably because it is counter-intuitive. This possibly doesn't hold for the average behavior, but proving it is a quite different matter.